# Young Adult novel set in underwater city

Tags: story-identification

This is my first post, so I hope I have this set out correctly.  I'm looking to identify a story that I read many years ago, probably written in late 70's or early 80's.  The main points I can remember are below but the plot concerned a young boy/man and an attempt to destroy an undersea city or habitat.

The main protagonist was the son of a diplomat and came from somewhere with lower than normal gravity, I recall one of the early scenes in the book with the boy swimming to build his leg muscles and a girl being in the pool when he arrives.  They talk and she tells the boy about the underwater city she lives in.

As earth gravity made the boy weak, his father sends him to the underwater habitat that the girl lives in, and once there he becomes involved in various adventures, discovering men with artificial gills and other elements that I can no longer remember.

I think the overall plot was to bring down the Earth government by destroying the habitat in an explosion.

Can anyone help identify the story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like **Crisis on Conshelf Ten** by Monica Hughes, published in 1977 also the subject of this question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138230/65768).

Quoting from the [Kirkus review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/monica-hughes-2/crisis-on-conshelf-ten/) gives most of the points you remember, including gravity problems, a girl, terrorism, and gillmen:

> When Kepler Masterman, the first child born and reared on Moon Colony, comes to Earth for a six-month stay he's unable to take the gravitational pressure and is sent to live on Conshelf Ten, an undersea community engaged in fish-farming and hydroponics. Kepler loves the weightlessness of scuba-diving but soon finds himself caught in a web of conspiracy. Conshelf, like Moon, is fighting for its independence, and Kepler discovers that Hilary, his friend and teacher, is an advocate of radical terrorism. Stranger still, he encounters a gillman, a human being surgically adapted to underwater life, although others on Conshelf insist that ""the gillers"" are mere legend.

Comment: Thanks for that, the review certainly has the elements that I remember.